# Applying padding/font size attributes to entire wordpress post

Tags: wordpress, post, padding, font-size

How can I set a standard font size and padding to an entire wordpress **post**?

For example, currently I use `p style="padding-right: 30px;padding-left: 60px;font-size: large"` for every single paragraph except for title tags.

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you want to use CSS (Cascading Style Sheets) ([tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=CSS/Getting_Started)).

For your current example, you can apply the styles to **every `<p>` element on the page** using:

```
<style type="text/css">
p {
  padding-right: 30px;
  padding-left: 60px;
  font-size: large;
}
</style>
```

You can also put the contents (excluding `<style>` tag) into an external file (.css), then address the file using `<link rel="stylesheet" href="PATH_TO_STYLESHEET" />`. Stick the `<link>` element in the `<head>` of your theme.

#### Since you are working within Wordpress...

You can open up your theme's style.css (or edit it within Wordpress by going to `Appearance > Editor`  in the dashboard). Just place the content from above (again, without the style tag) near the bottom of your stylesheet. If you only want to style `<p>` elements within the post body, you can use the selector `div.post p {...`. rather than simply `p {...`. WordPress uses [the "post" class, among others](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/post_class), for each post that is displayed.

Answer (score 0):

If you use something like this it will apply it to all the paragraphs

```
.post-class p {
    padding-right: 30px;
    padding-left: 60px;
    font-size: large;
}
```

You might have to adjust .post-class to whatever the theme is using.